# No shadows with Eevee, no render with cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, shadows

This is my first time using blender in a very long time and I'm trying to make a render of a board game I'm working on. I believe I have everything set up correctly but when rendering with Eevee don't get any shadows, and when rendering with cycles I get a grey screen. I don't know what's wrong with the cycles rendering but I think there's some sort of global illumination affecting the shadows in the Eevee rendering. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: I just donwloaded your file and switched the render engine to cycles, and the scene rendered fine.

Comment: there is definitely somethings strange about the scene settings, because in eevee, i deleted the light, and set the background color to black, and the scene was still fully illuminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your file, and there's a shadow in both cycles and eevee. I could comment it but my rep is <50. You could try to copy paste all objects from this .blend file, to a newly created with default settings and check if it's ok

eevee:
[image]

cycles:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, ahahaha

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the lighting! When I try to render with cycles I still get grey screen. Any clue as to why?

Comment: Have you tried adding another camera? Set it as active and try to render